# Input file turns wrong when put in a function

Tags: python, pandas, file, input

I am currently trying to use pandas to read what is basically a csv file (but officially .dat format) and plot the data inside.

```
def IofQ(folderout) : 
    Iofq = pd.read_csv("{}\Iofq.dat".format(folderout), sep='\t')    
    Graph = Iofq.plot()
    
    return Iofq
IofQ("E:\ECOLE\Stage_L2C_Backup\ESA_COLIS\25_07_2023_101output\R01154_long\OutputSALS\dunno")
```

However, when I call this function, I get the error :

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\ECOLE\\Stage_L2C_Backup\\ESA_COLIS\x15_07_2023_101output\\R01154_long\\OutputSALS\\dunno\\Iofq.dat'
```

As you can see, the date `25_07_2023` is read `x15_07` by the system and I have no idea why.
On top of this, if the path was wrong, the error would something like `could not find directory` I guess.

Does someone know where such an error comes from ?

Comment: Specifically, `\25` in a non-raw string literal is interpreted as an escape sequence to mean the single character with character code 25 in base-8 (i.e. 21 in base-10 and 15 in hexadecimal, which is why you see `\x15`). As per the linked question, you can fix this by any of (1) putting `r` before the literal to make it a raw string, (2) escaping the backslashes by doubling them, (3) using forward-slash instead of backslash. (For documentation, see the "Escape Sequences" table at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)